# Python-requests Session working with CSRF

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, csrf

So I've got two pieces of code.
This one works:

```
import requests

url = 'http://XXXXXX.com.au?xxxxx'
r = requests.get(url,auth = ('user', 'password'), headers = {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'Fetch'})
token = r.headers['x-csrf-token']
c = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(r.cookies)

reqData = {'param' : 'value'}
headers = {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token}
r = requests.post(url, auth = ('user', 'password'), data = reqData, headers = headers, cookies = c)
```

This one doesn't:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
url = 'http://XXXXXX.com.au?xxxxx'

s.auth = ('user', 'password')
s.headers.update({'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'Fetch'})
r = s.get(url)
token = r.headers['x-csrf-token']

c = s.cookies

reqData = {'param' : 'value'}
headers = {'x-csrf-token': token}
r = s.post(url, data=reqData, headers=headers, cookies=c)
```

I tried the second code with and without explicitly copying and passing by cookies, as well as converting it from cookiejar to dict. Still getting CSRF token validation failed.

I'm happy using the first option for now, but what exactly am I doing wrong with the Session? Could it be just an idiosyncrasy of the webserver in question?

Comment: Quick query: In the second code snippet the variable 'sapUrl' is it a typo ('sapUrl' is never assigned any value) ?

Comment: @JosephBijuCadavil yes kinda typo: I edited my code slightly, to make variables' names generic, and missed that line. I've now edited the original post to fix it.